# Scala sorting by ranking

Tags: scala, sorting

I try to sort a complex structure of case classes according to a certain criterion, which has several (a finite number) characteristics. The sorting should be done according to a ranking list.

Explained by following example:
I have artifacts with a field `bird` which can have the expressions blackbird, starling, raven, budgie as string. A sequence should be sorted in the order (not alphabetically)

1. starlings
2. blackbirds
3. budgies
4. ravens

The birds themselves may have dependencies on each other, so the order within the groups must not be changed.

What I tried so far was to first group them, then sort the groups and patch them back together. Yet it looked clumsy and two questions arose:

1. Will groupBy always keep the previous order? By looking at the ScalaDoc ref, it looks to me that it will.
2. Is there a more efficient/not so clumsy way to sort the groups then the following:

edit: added a complete example, fixed an issue

```
case class Abc(bird: String)
val grouped = Seq(Abc("budgies"), Abc("ravens"), Abc("starlings"), Abc("ravens"), Abc("starlings"), Abc("blackbirds"), Abc("blackbirds"), Abc("ravens"))
val lookup: Map[String, Int] = Map(
  "starlings" -> 1,
  "blackbirds" -> 2,
  "budgies" -> 3,
  "ravens" -> 4
)

object MyOrdering extends Ordering[Abc] {
  def compare(a: Abc, b: Abc): Int = lookup(b.bird) - lookup(a.bird)
}

println(grouped.toSeq.sorted(MyOrdering))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ordering is fixed for `Abc` it might look like this:

```
case class Abc(bird: String)

object Abc {
  implicit val ord: Ordering[Abc] =
    Ordering.by(abc => lookup.getOrElse(abc.bird, 0))

  val lookup: Map[String, Int] = Map(
    "starlings" -> 1,
    "blackbirds" -> 2,
    "budgies" -> 3,
    "ravens" -> 4
  )
}

val grouped = Seq(Abc("budgies"), Abc("ravens"), Abc("starlings"), Abc("ravens"), Abc("starlings"), Abc("blackbirds"), Abc("blackbirds"), Abc("ravens"))

println(grouped.sorted)
```

If there are different orderings then `Ordering.by` is still a good way to create different sort criteria.

Most of the standard sort algorithms are *stable*, which means that any elements that are equal according to the ordering will remain in the order they were before the sort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I flagged it as accepted, since it has mentioned the stable vs unstable sorting behaviour, that I had asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Is this close to what you're after? It's really rather hard to tell from your limited description.

```
val lookup: Map[String, Int] = 
  Map("starlings"  -> 1
     ,"blackbirds" -> 2
     ,"budgies"    -> 3
     ,"ravens"     -> 4).withDefaultValue(999)

case class CC(bird :String)

List(CC("ravens"),CC("starlings"),CC("budgies")) //etc.
  .sortBy(cc => lookup(cc.bird))
```

Comment: Kind of, since it is less verbose, thanks :) 
I was hoping that someone would suggest a different approach, but I think I will go with this solution for now.